# Changing "processing" to "processed" in tqdm

Tags: python, progress-bar, tqdm

I was wondering if it is possible to change the description in tqdm for when a loop is completed. At the start, I would like to have `Processing` as desc and when it is completed then `Processed`.

For instance:

```
count = 0
for i in tqdm(range(100), desc = "Processing", unit = "counts"):
   count += i
   print(count)
```

In this case it will have verbose with "Processing" even when it finishes. Any hint to make it change?
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be done using `set_description` function of tqdm. It has to be used after execution of last iteration, and before exiting the loop.

```
import tqdm
import time
count = 0
bar = tqdm.tqdm(range(100), desc = "Processing", unit = "counts")
for index,i in enumerate(bar):
   count += i
   time.sleep(0.1)
   #print(count)
   if index == len(bar)-1:
       bar.set_description(desc="Processed", refresh=True)
```